SpecFlow C# Visual Studio - Navigation Disabled
SpecFlow for VS 2022
2022.1.91.26832
Problem
Cannot navigate to code behind feature file steps.
Tried

delete the .vs file
delete %temp% files
delete autogenerated .cs files for .feature files.
close VS
re-open and rebuild

Info: OnSettingsInitialized: Project settings initialized: .NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0,SpecFlow:3.9.74
Warning: AndDiscoveryProviderSucceed: Error during binding discovery. 
Command executed:
  C:\git\engine-features-automation\BDTFeaturesAutomation\bin\Debug\net8.0> C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec c:\users\guyl\appdata\local\microsoft\visualstudio\17.0_7ad9ef81\extensions\ypciabcb.3gp\Connectors\Generic-net7.0\specflow-vs.dll discovery C:\git\engine-features-automation\BDTFeaturesAutomation\bin\Debug\net8.0\BDTFeaturesAutomation.dll C:\git\engine-features-automation\BDTFeaturesAutomation\specflow.json
Exit code: 4
Message: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethod(QCallModule module, Int32 methodToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethodHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 methodToken, ReadOnlySpan`1 typeInstantiationContext, ReadOnlySpan`1 methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethodHandle(Int32 methodToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodBase(RuntimeModule scope, Int32 typeMetadataToken)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeCustomAttributeData..ctor(RuntimeModule scope, MetadataToken caCtorToken, ConstArray& blob)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeCustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule module, Int32 tkTarget)
   at SpecFlowConnector.ReflectionExecutor.Execute(DiscoveryOptions options, Func`3 testAssemblyFactory, ILogger _log, IAnalyticsContainer analytics) in D:\a\1\s\Connectors\SpecFlow.VisualStudio.SpecFlowConnector.Generic\ReflectionExecutor.cs:line 15
   at SpecFlowConnector.Runner.ExecuteDiscovery(DiscoveryOptions options, Func`3 testAssemblyFactory) in D:\a\1\s\Connectors\SpecFlow.VisualStudio.SpecFlowConnector.Generic\Runner.cs:line 50
   at SpecFlowConnector.Runner.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Run>b__0(ConnectorOptions options) in D:\a\1\s\Connectors\SpecFlow.VisualStudio.SpecFlowConnector.Generic\Runner.cs:line 30
   at FunctionalExtensions.Map[TSource,TResult](TSource this, Func`2 fn) in D:\a\1\s\Connectors\SpecFlow.VisualStudio.SpecFlowConnector.Generic\NetExtensions\FunctionalExtensions.cs:line 5
   at SpecFlowConnector.Runner.Run(String[] args, Func`3 testAssemblyFactory) in D:\a\1\s\Connectors\SpecFlow.VisualStudio.SpecFlowConnector.Generic\Runner.cs:line 26
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: D. Path '', line 0, position 0.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at SpecFlow.VisualStudio.Connectors.OutProcSpecFlowConnector.Deserialize(RunProcessResult result, Func`2 formatErrorMessage)
Warning: AndDiscoveryProviderSucceed: The project bindings (e.g. step definitions) could not be discovered. Navigation, step completion and other features are disabled. 
  Please check the error message above and report to https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow.VS/issues if you cannot fix.


Which unit test provider are you using? Which .NET framework version are you using? Which version of the SpecFlow NuGet package are you using?

Have you tried repairing your Visual Studio installation?

Thanks, @GregBurghardt.  Will try.  .NET 8.0.  SpecFlow for VS 2022, 2022.1.91.26832.

I ran into this recently at work and (short version), the answer was to download & use Reqnroll instead: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Reqnroll.ReqnrollForVisualStudio2022
According to their website (https://specflow.org/) SpecFlow won't be available after today, which I suspect was known well before this week, as for instance their GitHub issues got nuked some time ago, ex: https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/2719#issuecomment-1934292742
